# Did Faith ever undergo the Cruciamentum?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer

The Tento di Cruciamentum, featured in the third season episode of *Buffy the Vampire Slayer* "Helpless", is a test slayers are supposed to go through on their 18th birthday. The slayer is weakened to the strength of an average human and is then locked somewhere with a particularly dangerous vampire. Did Faith Lehane ever experience the Cruciamentum for herself?

- I believe Faith is older than Buffy (Faith sometimes refers to and treats Buffy as a little sister) so Faith may have turned 18 before she was called as a slayer.
- Faith had a watcher before Giles. If Faith had not yet turned 18 when she was called, either that watcher or Giles would be expected to administer the test.
- Faith's first watcher is killed by a particularly nasty vampire, Kakistos. Speculation: Cruciamentum gone wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the "little sister" bit wasn't intended literally.  Faith had a harder life, so she saw herself as more "grown up" than Buffy.  (Aren't Slayers always called at roughly the same age?  That's what the "if they survive until their 18th birthday" aspect to the test seems to imply.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Faith didn't experience the Cruciamentum.

As you've rightly pointed out, Faith had at least one other Watcher prior to her 18th birthday. According to the Buffy novel "Go Ask Malice" (written largely from Faith's perspective) she was encouraged, by a slayer vision, to find out about the Cruciamentum by sneaking a peek at her Watcher's journals.

> *Read her diary. Read of the Cruciamentum.*
>   "The what?".
>   *Read of the betrayal to come*
>
> <sub><sup>[Go Ask Malice](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=omIjTj9kVNcC&pg=PA181&lpg=PA181&dq=cruciamentum+%22go+ask+malice%22&source=bl&ots=fInGJb5_qp&sig=4PbCt6LH3dn5azAGNYEqWY89eJg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiip6Whss_OAhWJECwKHU3EDL0Q6AEIHjAB#v=onepage&q=cruciamentum%20%22go%20ask%20malice%22&f=false)</sup></sub>

Once she'd found out about the ritual, there was little point going through with it.

Comment: You consider every book approved by Fox canon?

Comment: @neeshka - In thus instance there's no reason to believe that it's not. The events don't contradict subsequent episodes and the author has gone on to write several books and stories that are part of the main (fully canon) continuity.

Comment: Malice was well-received by the fans but no one calls it canon. None of the novels are, as Joss had nothing to do with them. As about RJL he wrote The Suicide King, Go Ask Malice & Back to the Garden (Tales of the Slayer) which of it you referring as part of the canon?

Comment: @neeksha - You seem to be getting quite worked up about this subject. Would you perhaps like to write an answer that you feel meets your standards of canonicity?

Comment: Thanks! This was just the kind of answer I was looking for. While its place in canon may be disputed, I think this is this is the best answer I'll get unless future Angel & Faith novels explore this part of Faith's past.

Comment: Um, sorry if i offended you. I was just curious what you consider canon. As for writing an answer it would be 'we dont know' & mere speculations as there's nothing definite on the subject, not even Faith's age. There are the novels, fanfiction and fan theories... but i am not sure SFF is a place where you can base your answer on such stuff...?

Comment: Was Faith with her old Watcher on her 18th birthday? The "Go Ask Malice" wiki page claims Faith's birthday is December 14, 1980, one month older than Buffy. Faith would be in Sunnydale on her 18th.

Comment: @neeshka - You may consider the novels to be non-canon, but they're at least licensed by the studio which must count for something. You might also want to note that Joss isn't above disavowing certain works (like the movie) add non-canon despite his input so it's not nearly as cut and dried as you might think. If you want to ask a question about buffy canon,  I would imagine several people would have a stab at it.

Comment: @valorum no need, i think I've got it now.  We on the Buffy forums only discuss seriously btvs, ats and the comic. Now i see it's different here on SFF.

Comment: @Neeshka There's nothing wrong with posting a new answer - having more than one answer to the same question is even encouraged here. If you write up an answer which is more canonical (at least by some definition) than Valorum's, that would be worth an upvote. Don't be discouraged by Valorum's brusqueness - he usually means well :-)